# Boolean property used as a statement in c++

Tags: c#, properties, c++-cli, boolean

I was translating some C++/CLI code to c# and I saw the below snippet within the constructor of a class.

```
if( !prop1 )
        prop2;
```

Prop1 and prop2 are 2 public boolean properties of the same class with only the get methods defined.

```
public:

 property  bool      prop1      { bool get(); }
 property  bool      prop2      { bool get(); }
```

What does the above statement mean? How can a boolean property be used as a statement on its own?
What would it translate to in c#?

Comment: It is possible to call a property getter only for its side effects, although it is not good design. Can you provide more of the context around that code and the property getter itself so we can see if something else is going on?

Comment: Do c++ have properties?

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't have properties... So I assume it's using a Microsoft extension. The only thing I can think of is that the getter method has side effects (otherwise there'd be no point in calling it). Very, very nasty code if that's the case.

Comment: The getter doesn't have any side effects. So, is there anything actually happening?

Comment: I think I may have mis-edited the second code block. Could someone please check? Or I'll reverse out.

Comment: @Tyler Durden; thanks. I've changed it back; leave clarity to the experts. Back in my box ...

Comment: Pls dont use managed-c++, use C++/CLI at least.

Comment: Is this really `managed-c++`, or is it C++/CLI? For the latter, your `prop1` and `prop2` don't look right (unless the get() is defined somewhere else).

Comment: corrected the tags and question to make it c++/cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be using a C++ extension of some sort, perhaps based on [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1600.html), I'm not really sure.

Regardless, it seems clear from what you've posted of the code that the statement in question is a no-op, so I'd just leave it out.

Interesting question though.

Comment: Sorry to put this bluntly, but you just don't have enough reputation for me to trust your answer.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm here primarily to learn, and this was an interesting one to research.

Comment: Chill, I was just messing with u ;) Like the spirit though :)

Comment: Unless this statement does have some hidden operation due to calling the bool, I don't believe C# would let you import it anyway, as it flags statements with no operations as errors.